# Spark Streaming is reading from Kafka topic and how to convert nested Json format into dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am able to read data from Kafka topic and able to print the data on the console using spark streaming.

I wanted the data to be in a dataframe format.

Here is my code:

```
spark = SparkSession  \
    .builder  \
    .appName("StructuredSocketRead")  \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ERROR') 
    
lines = spark  \
    .readStream  \
    .format("kafka")  \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","********")  \
    .option("subscribe","******")  \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")  \
    .load()

readable = lines.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

query = readable  \
    .writeStream  \
    .outputMode("append")  \
    .format("console")  \
    .option("truncate", "False")  \
    .start()
    
query.awaitTermination()
```

The output is in JSON file format. How to convert this into a dataframe?Please find the output below:

```
{"items": [{"SKU": "23565", "title": "EGG CUP MILKMAID HELGA ", "unit_price": 2.46, "quantity": 2}], "type": "ORDER", "country": "United Kingdom", "invoice_no": 154132541847735, "timestamp": "2020-11-02 20:56:01"}
```

Comment: Well, you've deserialized to a String, so now you need to define and apply a schema to `readable` https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

Comment: What is the output format you are looking for ? meanwhile refer this , similar type of question I have answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640565/get-data-from-nested-json-in-kafka-stream-pyspark/64640789#64640789

Answer (score 0):

from_json should be of help here + define json schema

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("type", StringType(), True),
        StructField("country", StringType(), True),
        ...
    ]
)

readable = lines.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
         .withColumn("value", (from_json("value", schema)))
         .select(col("*"), col("value.*"))
```

then you will get columns based on your json and schema and then you need to decide what you want to do about the item list, if you want to explode it as per previous response from dsk or keep it as nested list in a column.

Answer (score -1):

IICU, please use **`explode()`** and **`getItems()`** in order to create a Dataframe out of the json..

## Create the dataframe here

```
a_json = {"items": [{"SKU": "23565", "title": "EGG CUP MILKMAID HELGA ", "unit_price": 2.46, "quantity": 2}], "type": "ORDER", "country": "United Kingdom", "invoice_no": 154132541847735, "timestamp": "2020-11-02 20:56:01"}
df = spark.createDataFrame([(a_json)])
df.show(truncate=False)
+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----+
|country       |invoice_no     |items                                                                                |timestamp          |type |
+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----+
|United Kingdom|154132541847735|[[quantity -> 2, unit_price -> 2.46, title -> EGG CUP MILKMAID HELGA , SKU -> 23565]]|2020-11-02 20:56:01|ORDER|
+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

## Logic Here

```
df = df.withColumn("items_array", F.explode("items"))
df = df.withColumn("quantity", df.items_array.getItem("quantity")).withColumn("unit_price", df.items_array.getItem("unit_price")).withColumn("title", df.items_array.getItem("title")).withColumn("SKU", df.items_array.getItem("SKU"))
df.select("country", "invoice_no", "quantity","unit_price", "title", "SKU", "timestamp", "timestamp").show(truncate=False)
+--------------+---------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|country       |invoice_no     |quantity|unit_price|title                  |SKU  |timestamp          |timestamp          |
+--------------+---------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|United Kingdom|154132541847735|2       |2.46      |EGG CUP MILKMAID HELGA |23565|2020-11-02 20:56:01|2020-11-02 20:56:01|
+--------------+---------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: How does this help construct a Streaming Dataframe from Kafka?