# read pretty json format data through spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We read data present in hour format present in S3 through spark in scala.For example,

> spark.read.textFile("s3://'Bucket'/'key'/'yyyy'/'MM'/'dd'/'hh'/*").

spark.read.textFile reads records one line at a time so for example records that are present in jsonLines(full json data in one line) are read and can be parsed later to retrieve data from json.

Now,I have to read data which is having multiple json but in pretty format instead of json lines.Using same strategy gives corrupt record error.For example Dataset[String] obtained after reading through spark.read.textFile:

```
{
"a": 1, 
"b": 2
  }
```

is

```
_corrupt_record|
  +---------------+
  |              {|
  |       "a": 1, |
 |         "b": 2|
   |              }|
```

Input data :

```
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2"
}
{
"key1": "value1",
 "key2": "value2"
}
```

ExpectedOutput

```
+------+------+
|key1  |key2  |
+------+------+
|value1|value2|
|value1|value2|
+------+------+
```

This file has multiple pretty formatted json with delimiter between records as newline.

**Approaches already used**

- spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("") .This will not work as multiline requires data to be present in form of [{},{}].

**Approach working**

```
val x=sparkSession
.read
.json(sc
  .wholeTextFiles(filePath)
  .values
  .flatMap(x=> {x
  .replace("\n", "")
   .replace("}{", "}}{{")
   .split("\\}\\{")}))
```

I just wanted to ask if there is a better approach as the above solution is doing some slice and dice on data which might lead to performance issue for large data?Thanks

Comment: Aman we need to see the input data in a tabular format and the expected output

Comment: Meanwhile you can try this answer to check how to extract from a json format..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640565/get-data-from-nested-json-in-kafka-stream-pyspark/64640789#64640789

Comment: dsk,updated the question.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, can you please check the solution and help accept and upvote if that helped you

Answer (score 0):

This can be a working solution for you, use **from_json()** and correct **`schema`** in order to parse a json correctly

## Create the dataframe here

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(str([{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}, {"key1": "value3", "key2": "value4"}]))],T.StringType())
df.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'}]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, use **`explode()`** as the **`value/json`** column is a list in order to map correctly
And, finally use **`getItem()`** to extract the columns

```
df = df.withColumn('col', F.from_json("value", T.ArrayType(T.StringType())))
df = df.withColumn("col", F.explode("col"))
df = df.withColumn("col", F.from_json("col", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))
df = df.withColumn("key1", df.col.getItem("key1")).withColumn("key2", df.col.getItem("key2"))
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+------+------+
|value                                                                       |col                             |key1  |key2  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+------+------+
|[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'}]|[key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2]|value1|value2|
|[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'}]|[key1 -> value3, key2 -> value4]|value3|value4|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+------+------+

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: sorry I do not understand the answer.My query was to read a file from S3 which is present in form of multiline JSONS.I do not know the column names for the files and thus cannot do any operations that you mentioned.

Comment: Not an issue.. is it possible to share any of the sample file ? The above logic works in order to unpack a json file/column . the column names used here for representation propose only

Comment: Ya sure this is one sample file containing some records from a big file. http://pastie.org/p/36AaxjeLl7yehj4BUpxdjW .